# Form input value validation

Tags: javascript, validation, contact-form

I have a question about contact form. I am not good in `javascript`. Here we go to the question.

I have a contact form on my website and one of the field called `security` that is for anti-spammers purpose. Currently, all the fields(except `security`) will be validated by `javascript` where i got from somewhere else. And, the field of `security`, will be validated by php code when submit. The security field is a math question. If you have complete all other fields, but provided a wrong answer to the security field, you will be redirected to the form and be required to do it all over again. I don't want the form to be this way.

Here to test the form --> http://www.jornes.com

What i want is, if the answer to the math question is 50, visitors can only pass the validation and submit the form with a correct answer. I want this value to be validated by `javascript`.

I'm looking for a solution to make the contact form even better. Any solutions?

Below is the javascript to process my existing form.

```
function validateForm(){
    // set some vars
    var name = document.getElementById('name');
    var phone = document.getElementById('phone');
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var location = document.getElementById('location');
    var findus = document.getElementById('findus');
    var inquiry = document.getElementById('inquiry');
    var msg = '';

    if(name.value.length == ''){
        msg+= '*How shall i address you? \n';
        name.className = 'inpBoxError';
    }

    else if(name.value.length < 3){
        msg+= '-Your name is too short, my friend! \n';
        name.className = 'inpBoxError';
    }

    else if((name.value.length<3)||(/[^a-z\s\'\-\.]/gi.test(name.value))) { // invalid - must be minimum of 5 character only
        msg+= '-Please enter your name with words only! \n';
        name.className = 'inpBoxError';
    }

    else if ((phone.value.length == '')) { 
        msg+= '*You should have a cell phone, i guess?! \n';
        phone.className = 'inpBoxError';
    }



    else if ((phone.value.length<1)||(/[^0-9]/gi.test(phone.value))) { // invalid - must be minimum of 10 digits only
        msg+= '-Only Numeric for Phone Field!(Ex:0123456789) \n';
        phone.className = 'inpBoxError';
    }

    else if ((phone.value.length<10)||(/[^0-9]/gi.test(phone.value))) { // invalid - must be minimum of 10 digits only
        msg+= '-Please enter a valid phone number! "10 digits" \n';
        phone.className = 'inpBoxError';
    }

    else if ((email.value.length == '')) { 
        msg+= '*Email is also a good way for us to communicate. \n';
        email.className = 'inpBoxError';
    }

    else if(!/^([a-z0-9])([\w\.\-\+])+([a-z0-9]?)\@((\w)([\w\-]?)+\.)+([a-z]{2,4})$/i.test(email.value)) { // invalid
        msg+= '-Invalid email format! \n';
        email.className = 'inpBoxError';
    }

    else if(location.value.length == ''){
        msg+= '*Please tell me where are you from! \n';
        location.className = 'inpBoxError';
    }

    else if(location.value.length < 5){
        msg+= '-Location name is too short! I am not sure where is the place. \n';
        location.className = 'inpBoxError';
    }

    else if(purpose.value == ''){
        msg+= '*You contact me for...? \n';
        purpose.className = 'multipleError';
    }

    else if(findus.value == ''){
        msg+= '*How did you find me? Did i know you? \n';
        findus.className = 'inpSelectError';
    }

    else if(inquiry.value.length == ''){
        msg+= '*At least tell me something! \n';
        inquiry.className = 'messageBoxError';
    }

    else if(inquiry.value.length < 50){
        msg+= '-Your message is too short! "Minimum 50 characters." \n';
        inquiry.className = 'messageBoxError';
    }

    else if(security.value == ''){
        msg+= '*You must provide correct answer to submit this form! \n';
        security.className = 'inpBoxError';
    }

    // SUbmit form part
    if(msg == ''){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert(msg);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even the dumbest bot can parse Security: 7+3 perhaps you want to use words or images.

You can use a regex to validate the security form field but even this one could be analysed by spam bots. I would not validate this field in the frontend. The server should test it an in case of an error return the form again with prefilled with the former user input.

If you want you can add a hidden field, that should not filled at all. If your id or label of this hidden field is clever chosen many spam bots will fill something in, and you can use this information to block them.

Comment: Which means that javascript validation for security form field not recommended?

Comment: I would use the other way. Javascript works at the client. A spam bot could analyze it and fill in the correct values without reading the question at all.

Comment: I see. Perhaps, i have a better other than this now.